# Image used in parent window showing error pyimage9 does not exist at the time of showing in the child window

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to display the same image in the child window which was displayed in the parent window. I have added the following code

```
main_window.withdraw()

        create_account_window = Tb.Window(themename="darkly",title="TeXtCrYpTeR")
        create_account_window.maxsize(width=550,height=335)
        create_account_window.minsize(width=550,height=335)

        # disableing resizble factor
        create_account_window.resizable(False,False)

        # launching the app at the centre  of the screen

        screen_width = create_account_window.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = create_account_window.winfo_screenheight()

        app_width = 550
        app_height = 335

        x = (screen_width/2) - (app_width/2)
        y = (screen_height/2) - (app_height/2)

        create_account_window.geometry(f'{app_width}x{app_height}+{int(x)}+{int(y)}')

        # window icon
        create_account_window.iconbitmap(r'padlock.ico')
        icon = r'padlock.ico'
        create_account_window.iconbitmap(default=icon)

        create_account_window = Toplevel()
            
        img = Image.open("textcrypter.png")
        frame = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        frame_place = tk.Label(create_account_window,image=frame)
        frame_place.place(x=165,y=20)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Tkinter image not show up if created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function)

Comment: Why duplicating `create_account_window = Tb.Window` and `create_account_window = Toplevel()`?

Comment: Are you creating more than one instance of `Tk`?